# Add tableview cell with the value of UITextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITextField` in a `UITableView` header. When the user enters anything in the `UITextFields`, the entry gets added to a `NSMutableArray`.

I want to create a new `UITableCell` with the value of the `UITextField` entry whenever `textFieldShouldReturn` is called.

I tried using `reloadData` but that seems to empty my array completely.

Any suggestions? Thanks

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)task
{

[task resignFirstResponder];   
[self.tasksArray addObject:task.text];

NSLog(@"Test %@", self.tasksArray);
}
```

My cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
SwipeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[SwipeTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

[cell setDelegate:self];
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

// Setting the default inactive state color to the tableView background color
[cell setDefaultColor:self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
[cell.textLabel setText:self.task.text];
self.view = tableView;

cell.mode = SwipeTableViewCellModeExit;
return cell;
}
```

My `UITableView` header :

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
            viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

float width = tableView.bounds.size.width;
int fontSize = 18;
int padding = 1;

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,width, fontSize+11)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0];
view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
view.tag = section;

UITextField *task = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding, 2, 
                                           width - padding , fontSize + 11)];
task.text = @"Type here";
task.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
task.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
task.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
task.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
task.delegate = self;
task.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];

[view addSubview:task];
self.tasksArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

return view;
}
```

`viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
self.tasksArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
self.title = @"Test";
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:227.0 / 255.0 
                                                   green:227.0 / 255.0 
                                                    blue:227.0 / 255.0 
                                                   alpha:1.0]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:backgroundView];

}
```

Comment: Suggestion: show code.

Comment: Show us your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @user2747220 Sorry but can you also show the rest of the tableview delegate methods?

Comment: why this `self.view = tableView;` ?

Comment: That's a good question. I'll take it out but I don't think it will fix my issue.

Comment: Abudllah, what do you specifically want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove** `[cell.textLabel setText:self.task.text];`

And then,

Insert `[self.yourTableOutletName reloadData];` after `[self.tasksArray addObject:task.text];`

Now your code will **reload the tableView** after adding a object into `self.taskArray`.

And then,

To **reflect your array in tablView** use this line.

Insert `[cell.textLabel setText:[self.tasksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];` after `[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];`

Comment: Thanks Akshit, I feel like I'm almost there. It's not creating a new row, it only changes the value of the current cell if 1 is displayed. I'll try to figure it out but if you have a suggestion please let me know.

Comment: does your `numberOfRowsInSection` returns `self.tasksArray.count` ?

Comment: Yes it does indeed. I use a Mutable Array and I alloc/init it in viewdidload. Would it be an issue?

Comment: @user2747220 . no, alloc/init is not an issue.

Comment: Sorry I meant that alloc/init in the header, not viewdidload. I updated the thread with my header code. I have nothing in didselectRowAtIndexPath, and the numberOfRowsInSection is self.tasksArray.count.

Comment: got your problem. @user2747220 , move alloc/init for `self.taskArray` to `viewDidLoad` .

Comment: @user2747220 , because `viewForHeader` calls everytime the table is reloaded. then it will be allocated each time. And when an object is allocated it looses all it's previous values. So, use `self.taskArray = [NSmutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];` in your `viewDidLoad` ..

Comment: If I move it, it crashes the app because the array is empty. If I initWithObjects:@"test object", nil], it crashes anyway. Console log returns that the index is beyond bounds. That's very interesting interesting because I feel like it will teach me about memory management. My property is strong and nonatomic, what should I change it to?

Comment: Advantage of using `self.taskArray = [NSmutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];` is that u don't have to worry about releasing it manually if you are not using ARC otherwise skip the rest of the message !!!!. When you alloc object then you have to dealloc it manually using `release` method. In above case, you alloc/init self.taskArray everytime the tableView is loaded. So it consumes too much memory.

Comment: `strong and nonatomic` is just fine. There is something else. Post your `viewDidLoad` also.

Comment: View did load is posted.

Comment: do you want something like this https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3PZzP2RSGt4VzJCV2NBbkVpTUE/edit?usp=sharing ?

Comment: I think this will help me to figure it out. Thanks for your help, you're amazing

Answer (score 0):

This line pulls the data incorrectly: [cell.textLabel setText:self.task.text];
self.view = tableView;

It should be from your array.

Also you never reload data, that should be the last line in textFieldShouldReturn